# linux comm produces different results when run from crontab

Tags: cron, comm

I am running the following command from a bash script:

```
comm -23 file1 file2 > file3
```

(`file1` & `file2` are de-duped and sorted first)

This produces a `file3` that contains rows unique to `file1` only (what I want).

When the script is run from the command line, there are no issues. However, when it is run from the `crontab`, it produces a much larger (incorrect) `file3`. The `crontab` user is the same as the logged-in user when run manually.

Any clues as to what would cause such a discrepancy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Almost *all* disparities between programs running from your shell and from within `cron` have to do with the environment.

The first thing to do is to run something like `env` in both places and capture the output. It may be something as simple as running a different executable because the paths are different.

Another possibility is that the `LC_COLLATE` setting is different between the two environments. From the `info` page:

> Before `comm` can be used, the input files must be sorted using the collating sequence specified by the `LC_COLLATE` locale.

The `--check-order` option may be a way to check this, causing a fatal error on unsorted input (including unsorted based on a different collation than you think you're using).

Comment: "locale" from command line returns LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8", from crontab script it returns LC_COLLATE="POSIX". Not sure what all this means and what to do about it exactly, but sounds like this is the cause. Thanks

Comment: Should be easy enough to check, @Ben, set `LC_COLLATE` to `POSIX` on the command line and see if they start agreeing with each other.

Comment: I am actually running the Linux 'comm' (and sort, join, etc..) from a PHP client-mode script using "shell_exec()". I have added putenv('LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8'); to the beginning of the php script. This has solved the issue. The cron no longer behaves differently. Thanks again paxdiablo for your insights.